# Get all dates from one table and get total records of each date from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which will accept `startdate`, `enddate`, `timezone`,`user` and `host`

and will display count of all records on each day in the given daterange.

I have created a stored procedure for this using the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` following is my code:

```
USE [database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_getPageViewCountDayWise]           Script Date: 24/02/2015 10:25:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getPageViewCountDayWise]

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
   --<@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>,
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>

    @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate DATETIME,
    @timezone VARCHAR(6),
    @user varchar(500),
    @host VARCHAR(200)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NULLIF(@user, '') IS NULL
    begin 
        set @user = @host+'/%'
    end 
    else
    begin
        set @user = @host+'/'+@user+'/%'
    end

   select * from [dbo].[ExplodeDates](@startdate,@enddate)

    select CAST(a.DateTime AS DATE) AS Date, count(*) as count
    from [dbo].[DateRange](@startdate,@enddate) AS b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserLog AS a
    ON CAST(b.thedate AS DATE) = CAST(dbo.[ConvertDateToFromTimeZone]   (a.DateTime, @timezone) AS DATE) 
   and a.Url like @user
    group by CAST(a.DateTime AS date)

   END
```

`[dbo].[DateRange]` is a user defined function which will return a table having all dates in the particular date range as follows:

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ExplodeDates]    Script Date:       24/02/2015 11:12:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ExplodeDates](@startdate datetime, @enddate   datetime)
returns table as
return (
with 
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 t1, N3 t2)
,N5 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N4 t1, N4 t2)
,N6 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N5 t1, N5 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N6)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1
);
```

and

`dbo.[ConvertDateToFromTimeZone]` is a function which convert each date into the given timezone

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ConvertDateToFromTimeZone]       Script Date: 24/02/2015 11:14:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertDateToFromTimeZone]
(
   -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @date DATETIMEOFFSET,
    @offset VARCHAR(6)
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   -- Declare the return variable here
   DECLARE @Result DATETIME

   -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Result= SWITCHOFFSET (@date , @offset)
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
```

suppose I want to see number of records between 2nd feb 2015 to 5 feb 2015 per day the result should be

```
Date        Count
02/02/2015    10
03/02/2015     2
04/02/2015     0
05/02/2015     3
```

but my procedure is returning something like this

```
Date          Count
NULL           2
02/02/2015     10
03/02/2015     2
05/02/2015     3
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.DateTime` is the right hand side of a left-join and as such is possible to return nulls. It appears you want the left side of the join instead, which is `b.thedate`. Therefore you should select `b.thedate` instead of `a.DateTime` in your query (and most likely group by this instead as well).